# How to open SQLite connection in WAL mode in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

How to open SQLite connection in WAL mode in iOS. Normally I am using `sqlite3_open_v2` to open it.

Here is the C# answer but how to do that in Swift?

[How to open SQLite connection in WAL mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870104/how-to-open-sqlite-connection-in-wal-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) says:

> The WAL journaling mode is persistent; after being set it stays in effect across multiple database connections and after closing and reopening the database.

So it is enough that `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL` is executed once after creating the database file. Nothing special is needed when opening it later.

Answer (score 9):

You can run the pragma statement for WAL mode after opening the database.

```
sqlite3_exec(dbHandle, "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;", 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry I marked @CL's answer as the right answer because it explains more. But I up vote your answer too. Thank you.